# sending DM to multiple users in Discord using Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm using this code to send a direct message to multiple users:

```
@bot.command(name="dm")
async def dm(ctx,message, *users: discord.User):
    for user in users:
        await user.send(message)
```

the problem is i can only send one word with this code.
Has someone any ideas how to send a whole message?

Comment: You can put the message in double quotes

Comment: thanks a lot man! Didn't knew that could work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the special converter [`commands.Greedy`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Greedy)

```py
@bot.command()
async def dm(ctx, users: commands.Greedy[discord.User], *, message):
    for user in users:
        await user.send(message)
```